# Repeat SQL query to return results per date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First question hoping you can help me out as I just can't seem to achieve my desired results. I have written the code below

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = '20160102'
DECLARE @Part varchar(9) = '49ESNWH00'
DECLARE @Size Varchar(9) = '3050X2050'

;
With Parents as
(
   Select 
       par.StockTrans_Id, Par.PartNo, 
       par.TransactionDate, par.Size,
       Par.Quantity
   from 
       StockTrans as Par
   Where 
       Par.ParentYN = 'Y'
       And Par.TransactionDate <= @Date
       And Par.PartNo = @Part
)
Select 
    @Date as Date,
    par.PartNo, par.size,
    SUM(st.Quantity) [Quantity]
from 
    Parents as Par
left Join 
    StockTrans as st on Case
                          When st.RefNo < 10 then ('00'+ Convert(Varchar,st.refno)) + '.' + st.PartNo
                          When st.RefNo < 100 then ('0'+ Convert(Varchar,st.refno)) + '.' + st.PartNo
                          Else Convert(Varchar,st.refno) + '.' + st.PartNo
                        end = par.StockTrans_Id
Where 
    St.TransactionDate <= @date
    and par.Size = @Size
group by 
    Par.PartNo, par.Size
having 
    SUM(st.Quantity) > 0
```

This returns me the data below:

[image: Data output]

This data is correct and if you change the Date in the scalar variable `@Date` then it happily tells you the stock position on that date.

What I need to be able to do however is present this stock position on days within a set of dates. Effectively generating a table of data something like the below (with start and end date also being variables):

[image: Desired Output]

How do I repeat the query per date?

Comment: Is `St.TransactionDate` a date field where the time is always midnight, or does it have the time as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply have the range of dates stored in a temporary table and join that table with "And Par.TransactionDate". It should happily give you the result for all dates from the "range of dates"